# Simple Cron task in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, cron, osx-lion, crontab

I am trying the Cron facility in Mac OS X Lion, but it does't seem to work.

The crontab looks like this:

```
MacBook-Air-de-Vincent:run vincentle$ crontab -l
MAILTO=bxxxxxxxx@gxxx.com
* * * * * (echo 'plop')
MacBook-Air-de-Vincent:run vincentle$
```

I would expect to see a "plop" written in the terminal every minute but I do not.

Why do I not see this?

Comment: Why would you expect Cron to write to your terminal? You've provided a MAILTO. Have you checked your inbox?

Comment: As an aside, the parentheses around the command line are superfluous.

Comment: For what I've read, MAILTO is supposed to send debug email.

Answer (score 1):

fwiw, cron is deprecated in Lion.

You should look to switch from cron to launchctl.

Comment: Please give an example of how to achieve the same using `launchctl`.

Comment: Please specify the official source for `cron` deprecation.

Comment: Be sure to read past the initial blurb, to the section, "Timed jobs using cron".

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html

Comment: @DanielBeck deprecated is such an ugly word. They simply added something else, left cron there, favor the new thing then call it 'deprecated'. Using on cron on Mavericks now. Deprecated? Not yet. Expect it to be there at least a few more foreseeable releases? Yes. [See here for answer to your question](http://web.archive.org/web/20060314034955/http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html) That article is from 2005 and we still have cron

Comment: @Michael.M: Are you sure you wanted to respond to me?

Comment: @DanielBeck Yup. You asked: "Please specify the official source for cron deprecation" I answered [See here for answer to your question](http://web.archive.org/web/20060314034955/http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html) because the official Apple article has a dedicated section there entitled "Migrating from cron" because, well, they want people to be "Migrating from cron" ... right? My comment is wordy because I want point out that almost a decade after the article, we still have cron. i.e.: take it with a limp of salt

Comment: @Michael.M: FWIW I think Snips' comment linking to a still published article is more useful. It even mentions cron is still supported (on current OS X), but still deprecated. Note that AFAIU deprecated does not mean it's gone or broken, it just means it should not be used (and often that something else should be used instead), usually because it's expected to be removed some time in the future.

Comment: @DanielBeck Sure. I simply thought you might *also* be interested in seeing the earliest official post with a date, which Snips' does not provide. I for one, was interested in knowing that.

Answer (score 0):

Cron is deprecated however crontab is not. Run `man crontab` and that'll give you what you want to know.

Comment: Am I confused or is he already using crontab?

Answer (score 0):

Besides whether or not cron is deprecated, this would not do what you want, not even in Linux.

Cron runs as a background process. The specific type is called a '[daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing))' (pronounced demon). As such it has no terminal, and no terminal to write to. Its stdout and stderr are hooked to mail. Normally, you'd drop to your local inbox on your computer, but you've supplied a MAILTO setting, which redirects mail to that email address.  This setup **should** send an email consisting solely of 'plop' to bxxxxxxxx@gxxx.com, every minute. All output goes to this mail, not just debugging output.

For testing, I usually do a touch file someplace in /tmp.  A cronjob of `date > /tmp/testdate.txt` or equivalent will show you if and how often your cron fires.